# Firebase Authentication Not showing my User Data

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I create many Projects and Try in different Browser With different IDs But Still, but I am Facing the Same Problem Please Help Me To Solve This Issue.

[image]

This is my file in Flutter Projects.

main.dart

```
import 'package:final_mini_project/screens/login_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp(),));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LoginPage();
  }
}
```

Login Page

```
import 'package:final_mini_project/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:final_mini_project/screens/signup_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _email = TextEditingController();
  final _pass = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 40,),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _email,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Email",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _pass,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Password",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                      SignInMethod();
                      // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(),));
                  },
                  child: Text("Login"),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      minimumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(400, 45))
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (
                          context) => SignUpPage(),));
                    },
                    child: Text("Not Have account ? SignUp Here")),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  Future SignInMethod() async{
    try{
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _email.text.trim(), password: _pass.text.trim()).then(
              (value) => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(),))
      );
    }
    on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              content: Text(e.toString()))
      );
    }
  }

}
```

Signup Code

```
import 'package:final_mini_project/screens/login_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpPage> createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _email = TextEditingController();
  final _pass = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 40,),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _email,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Email",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _pass,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Password",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    SignUpMethod();
                  },
                  child: Text("SignUp"),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      minimumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(400,45))
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpPage(),));
                    },
                    child: Text("Alredy Have account ? Login Here")),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
  Future SignUpMethod()  async {
    try
    {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _email.text.trim(), password: _pass.text.trim())
      .then((value) => 
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage(),))
      );
    }
    on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              content: Text(e.toString())));
    }
  }

}
```

Home Page

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
       body: Column(
         children: [
           Center(
             child: Text(auth!.email.toString())
           )
         ],
       ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Welcome Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WelcomePage> createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

When I run the application all things works write, but it's not showing any data in my Firebase console.

Login And SignUp also work well.

[image]

I enabled Email Authentication:

[image]

I am Developing Simple Flutter Application For My Collage Project .

Comment: Even When Push Data in Firebase Real Time That data is also not showing in Firebase Console.

Comment: Is it still not showing any data?

Comment: How are you able to confirm that a user can login and sign up successfully? When a user goes through the sign up, is their information stored successfully?

Comment: When I am run application in device as well as emulator is work well . If I created account then able to login others wise it's show please create account. After creating account I am able to login my account. I am going my home page .But if I manually add user in firebase Console that show error that user not available please create account.so disconnected between firebase Console and device.